# Java - vector of ints vs. vector of int arrays

Tags: java

I am learning Java for a homework assignment, and have several very beginner questions. Not sure if here is the best place to post them, if not please point me in the right direction.

```
Vector<int[]> zed = New Vector<int[]>
```

this is the data structure I have to work with for a specific question. I think this question is probably dumb, but is this a vector of int arrays, or simply a vector of ints? I've read that Int[] gives an array of strings, and then wrapping this in Vector<> logically would give a vector of int arrays, correct?

Thanks,

this java coding is within a hadoop environment if that matters as well.

Comment: there is no `Int` `type` or `class` in Java !

Comment: Don't use Vector... only use Vector if you need a thread safe implementation. You should be using the `List` interface.

Comment: this structure of an object was given to me though, i didn't write that, just trying to understand

Comment: how would i construct this as a list rather than a vector?

Comment: `List<Integer[]>` instead of `Vector<Integer[]>`, collections cannot hold primitive types, BUT it can hold arrays of primitive types, so `int[]` would be ok.

Comment: this java coding is within a hadoop environment if that matters as well, i will try the list of integers though

Comment: `Vector` is ancient, and only comes up in outdated textbooks. Use `ArrayList` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need to do:

```
Vector<int[]> zed = new Vector<int[]>();
```

The correct type in Java is `int` not Int, and since you are initializing the `Vector` object, you need to call its constructor just like above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a vector of int arrays.  In this case, it might be used to represent a two-dimensional grid, where the vector elements represent rows and the array elements represent columns.

Comment: There is no `Int` in java ! it must be `Integer` because vector is a Generic class , or sometimes we have `int` type , I've never seen `Int` in java

Comment: I was reading that, rightly or wrongly, as `int[]`.  Didn't spot the upper-case I.  But that's a side matter IMO.

Comment: some documentation i've found says that int is a primitive type. int has worked in my code thus far.

Comment: when you are using a generic class you must use a class , `Vector<Integer> a = new Vector<>();`

Comment: `Vector<Student> s = new Vector<>();`